# Add to object with every iteration without replacing

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6, iteration

I have an object outside of the function that I want to populate with every iteration and call that object after the iteration is done but I am only able to see the last element in my object. How do I add to object instead of replacing?

My code:

```
let myobj = {};
const func1 = async (arg) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  const response = await axios_Func({ graphQL query });
  console.log(`${response.data.name} - ${table_id}`);
  myobj["name"] = response.data.name;
  myobj["id"] = table_id;
  await func2({ query: graphQL_query, table_id });
}

const func2 = async (result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({ query: tables(123) });
  let prod = await getAllTables({ query: tables(321) });
  let prod_id = new Set();
  result.data.data.table.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d. connector != null && !(d.name in dev))
      prod_id.add(prod[d.name]["id"]);
  });
  prod_id = [...prod_id];
  prod_id.map((x) => createOne({ query: graphQL_query(x) });
  return Promise.all(prod_id.map((x) => func1({ query: graphQL_query(x) }));
});

const callback = () => console.log(myobj);

const execute = async () => {
  await func1()
  callback()
}
```

`myobj` is returning the last element in the object rather than the 5 elements it is supposed to have been populated with.

How do I get my object to have all the elements?

Comment: The object properties should be arrays if you want them to hold multiple values. Or make an array of objects instead of a single object.

Comment: Which loop are you talking about? I don't see any loop that updates `myobj`.

Comment: @Barmar `func1` and `func2` call each other till the function finishes running the `forEach` in `func2`

Comment: I see `await func2` in `func1`, but where is `func2` calling `func1`?

Comment: @Barmar, once the `forEach` ends the function stops

Comment: @Barmar, I edited my code to call `func1`

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that an object can only have one property with a given name. Every time you do `myobj["name"] = response.data.name;` you're replacing the name, not adding another name.

Comment: @Barmar, I get that. Is there a way to add instead of replacing?

Comment: Like I said, make it an array. `myobj = {name: [], id: []}`. Then you can do `myobj.name.push(response.data.name)`

Comment: Or `myobj = []` and then `myobj.push({name: response.data.name, id: table_id})`

Comment: @Barmar, this works! Thanks! If you add it as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array to hold multiple objects.

```
let myarray = [];
const func1 = async (arg) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  const response = await axios_Func({ graphQL query });
  console.log(`${response.data.name} - ${table_id}`);
  const myobj = {};
  myobj["name"] = response.data.name;
  myobj["id"] = table_id;
  myarray.push(myobj);
  await func2({ query: graphQL_query, table_id });
}
```